# How to get original system command after overwriting it with a function?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, .profile

I'm at a Hackathon right now so if someone would answer this soon, you'd be doing me a huge favor.

I've written a function called ls() in my .profile that looks like this:

```
ls() {

  if(some condition);
    do something
  else
    ls; #(CALL TO ORIGINAL ls SYSTEM CALL)
  fi

}
```

But here when it goes to the else part, it just enters an infinite loop

How can I call the original ls system call in else
Or, how can I make ls behave differently in one folder and normally in the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the full path to the executable:

```
/bin/ls
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 3):

The `command` built-in performs command lookup without considering functions:

```
ls() {

  if(some condition);
    do something
  else
    command ls
  fi

}
```